# CircleCI and Source Tracking

Tags: scratch-org, circleci

I am using CircleCI to do the "vanilla" process as defined in the DX tech doc.  Working OK.  Here is the scratch org create and push section of the yaml file:

```
  - run:
      name: Setup Org
      command: |
        echo 'Create/Push'
        ls -al
        pwd
        echo 'Here we go!'
        sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid $HUB_CONSUMER_KEY --jwtkeyfile .circleci/server.key --username $HUB_SFDC_USER --setdefaultdevhubusername -a hub            
        sfdx force:org:create -s -f .circleci/project-scratch-def.json -a circle_build_$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM --wait 4
        sfdx force:source:push -u circle_build_$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM
```

Here is my question:  How do I take advantage of "Source Tracking" in this scenario?  My package is huge and takes 30 minutes to deploy to the scratch org using the push command.  However, if I could use Source Tracking only changed files would have to be pushed.  In my current script I create a fresh scratch org each time so I guess Source Tracking is not an option....

Does anyone have an alternative approach with an example file that -- for example -- persists a scratch org all day and only sends source-tracked changes in the push?

Ugh:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, you want to create a scratch org every time your build process is triggered. This ensures your package integrity and that the whole process runs when you change or add features to your package. Once the build process is completed and your package deployed and tests passed, the scratch org should be deleted.

I hope you are not doing this on your feature branches, but rather a main dev branch which starts the build after you have successfully merged from a feature branch.
Source tracking will be beneficial when developing features locally and pushing changes to your feature scratch  org.